# Android - Explore my Application Data

Tags: android, eclipse, file, explorer

I'm developing my Android application with Eclipse IDE.
I'd like to view my application's data (saved in internal storage as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)).
"File Explorer" in Eclipse doesn't open the "data" folder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "File Explorer" in Eclipse doesn't open the "data" folder

That will be true on hardware. You cannot view your application's data via a file explorer.

One workaround is to add a backup-and-restore feature to your app that copies your application's data to external storage on demand (e.g., options menu item). Not only will you be able to use that to examine your data, but your users benefit as well.

Answer (score 10):

An other way of doing is to root your phone, then explore your files using shell.

With a rooted phone :

1. go to the adb folder in a terminal (on your computer)
2. `adb shell`
3. `su`
4. `cd /data/data/the.package.name.of.your.app`

And there you are! You can look at your files :-)

If you want to have direct access to those files on eclipse, you need to give access to them.

Well, if you are on a dev phone, you can give full access to all the files in /data/data

Of course this is something you should never do under any circumstances on regular basis...

Simply use [Busybox](https://market.android.com/details?id=stericson.busybox) to copy the folder you are looking for in your sdcard

1. Install busybox (most rooting procedures install it automatically)
2. go to the adb folder in a terminal (on your computer)
3. `adb shell` (to enter a shell inside your phone
4. `busybox` to check that it is installed correctly
5. `busybox chmod a+rwx /data`
6. `busybox chmod -R a+rwx /data/data`

Et Voila :-)
Now you should be able to access all you files on eclipse directly!

Comment: Holly xxx ! After 2 hours of rooting & xxxing I came across this, and it just solve everything. But please, for someone that has never doing anything with "root" - it should be added that: after installing busybox, please go to some terminal app (after step 2) and then you can type in from step 3

Answer (score 1):

You can access the sandbox of your app with `adb` (sdk > platform-tools > adb). Connect your device with USB and run the following commands in your shell.

```
adb shell
run-as com.mydomain.myapp
```

You don't have to root your device, but it does not work with all devices.

Comment: Did not work for me. It said "Package <my package name> has corrupt installation"!

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclips select "devices" select a drop down button called "Menu View" then reset adb, that's it!!

It might need you to restart your emulator/avd device.